# Vaadin Menu Bar, space between caption and icon for an item

Tags: css, vaadin, menuitem, menubar, vaadin8

I have a menu bar with some items. Each item has a caption and icon. Problem is that the caption and icon are very close to each other. Here it is:

[image]
How can I set some space between caption and icon?

This is my simple code:

```
MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
menuBar.setSizeFull();
menuBar.addStyleName(CSS.commom-menu-bar);
menuBar.addItem("import", VaadinIcons.DOCTOR,(selectedItem) ->  importDocs());
HorizontalLayout menuBarLayout = new HorizontalLayout(menuBar);
menuBarLayout.setWidth("100%");
setContent(menuBarLayout)
```

and css:

```
.v-menubar-common-menu-bar{
direction: rtl;
text-align: right !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your working code..?

Comment: @ankitapatel code is provided now! :)

Comment: This code is not helpful. Can you share working snippet code..?

Comment: either add padding-right to the text or padding-left to the image?

Comment: Have you tried: `menuBar.addItem("import", action).setIcon(icon)` ?

Comment: So what is your actual requirement? If you have a look at [Valo demo](https://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/#!menubars) the menu item icons have some space between the icon and text. Or do you want to put the icon to the right of the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a bit more CSS for your Icon-element:

```
.v-menubar-commom-menu-bar{
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right !important;
}

.v-menubar-commom-menu-bar .v-icon
{
    padding-left: 10px;     
}
```

If you use SASS, you'll also have to recompile the theme and maybe reload Browser-Cache for the changes to take effect.

[Screenshot of my local working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VjWb.png)